# Twitter4j IllegalStateException: Authentication credentials are missing

Tags: twitter4j

I saw related posts and it didn't help me with this issue.
Below is the code and am getting IllegalStateException, Authentication credentials are missing.
Please help me with this error.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("XXXX")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XXXXX")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("XXXX")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XXXX");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getSingleton();
    Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j sample");
    QueryResult result = null;
    result = twitter.search(query); //error occurs in this line
    for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
        System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" +      status.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You code is fine , just one mistake you did in this line ,

```
 Twitter twitter = tf.getSingleton();
```

The configuration object you provided won't be set in the singleton ,unless you use `getInstance()` method, so use this

```
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
```